# subview disappeared from visible area in the view on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, storyboard

I've a box container on a view (tab view in my case).
did few things on the other tab, and when I came back - the view disappeared, but I could still see it on the view tree on the left.

**apparently it moved outside of visible boundaries.**

how do I move the view back to it's place?
(without using the mouse)

**This is how it how is should be:**

(and then imagine the selected box has gone outside of visible area)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I've found for moving the lost view:

1. open the storyboard as a source Code file (right click on storyboard, Open as > source code)
2. search for the lost view by his name on the source code

[image]

3. change the location of the view on the code: (x=0; y=0)

   ```
    <customView fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RjJ-3C-kXQ" userLabel="LostView">
          <rect key="frame" x="0" y="0" width="383" height="96"/>
   ```

Comment: man, have you heard about layout constraints ? :) if you want your views to be displayed properly and "not getting lost" you should put constraints on your views. At least I haven't seen anything in your question description that shows that.

Comment: Hi, @Fawkes - constraints are good for runtime. I meant that the box was disappeard from the storyboard view, not at run time.

Comment: Then if you set the constraints good enough and you use Xcode, you should be able to just click on "update frames" menu under a button in the right corner in storyboards. The button has an icon with a triangle inside, which will update the views as needed. Or there is no need to get into the xml of a storyboard, you should be able to set the frame in the attributes inspector.